# Android Studio - CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout e FloatingActionButton não instanciados

Tags: android

Eu comecei criando uma nova aplicação, mudei o tema do projeto e obtive o seguinte erro:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat
>   theme (or descendant) with the design library.    at
>   android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)
>     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:172)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:458)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:170)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:103)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:190)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
>     at
>   android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)  at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:223)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
>     at
>   com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:366)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
>     at
>   com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
>     at
>   com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>     at
>   com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>     at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Não há necessidade do termo em inglês.

Answer (score 1):

O erro é auto explicativo

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the
>   design library

Se você estiver usando a design library, deve obrigatóriamente usar o Tema `Theme.AppCompat` ou algum derivado dele.

Comment: Mas então como deve proceder para usar outros temas?
Devo retirar a design library do código?

Comment: @user36323 Ou não use a design library ou modifieque-a conforme suas especificações, crie um tema novo com a Theme.Appcompat como base.

Answer (score 1):

Usa o Theme.AppCompat como pai dos seus temas em styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
</style>
```